# Scroll Buffering in Windows Applications

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll

How is scrolling typically handled in a Windows application that has computationally expensive graphics to render?  For example, if I am rendering a waveform graph of a sound, after processing the wave form from a peakfile, should I:

- Render the **entire** graphical representation to an in-memory GDI surface, and then simply have a scrollable control change the start/end of the render area?
- Render the visible portion of the wave only.  In a separate thread, process any new chunks of the graphc that come into view.
- Render the visible portion of the wave, plus a buffer.  This way, there's less of a chance of the user seeing "blank" or "currently rendering" portions of the waveform.  Still, if a user quickly scrolls to a distant area, the whole section will be blank until rendering is complete.

The problem is, many applications handle this in different ways.

For example:

**Adobe Acrobat** - renders blank pages during scroll unless page is in cache.  Any pages that would be visible within the document render area are rendered in a separate thread and are presented opon completion.

**Microsoft Word** - Essentially, the same as above.  Documents are separated into distinct pages, so each page is processed/rendered on an as-needed basis and added to a cache.

**Internet Explorer** - Unknown. It appears that an entire "webpage" is rendered in graphic memory, no matter how many "screens" worth of graphic data it consumes.  Theoretically, with a web page that scrolls for 10 or 15 screen lengths, this could mean 50-60MB worth of graphic memory consumption.  Could anyone with experience with WebKit or FireFox explain whether or not the rendering engine favors consuming a ton of memory, or tries to render peices of the page "on the fly" to conserve memory?

If it helps, my application is based on C#, .NET 3.5, and WinForms.

Answer (score 1):

This is a complexity vs. user experience trade-off.  Your third option will give you the best user experience (they can start to see things right away and start to work).  It is also the most complex to code (will take the longest to develop, with the most amount of bugs to kill).

The "correct" solution depends on how "expensive" expensive is, and on the demands of your user base.  I would select the option with the least complexity that will provide a user experience that will satisfy the bulk of the customers:

*Make it as complex as it needs to be, but no more complex than that.*

Answer (score 1):

I think this is actually a memory-usage versus a processor-usage tradeoff.  Your first option (rendering the entire wave on an appropriately-sized canvas, and then moving that canvas around with only a visible window portion showing) might be the best approach, assuming you have enough memory for it.  After an initial rendering delay, the user experience will be smooth and seamless.

If you don't have enough memory for this, then you have to render the visible portion on the fly.  I've written this application (WAV data viewer) many times, and usually GDI+ is more than fast enough to render portions (even large portions) of WAV data in realtime (with a high framerate above 30 fps, which produces perfectly smooth animation).  The key to this, however, is not to render each sample value as a separate point - this would be dog slow.  What you want to do is for each pixel on your X axis, scan the corresponding chunk of WAV samples to get the minimimum and maximum sample value, and then render a single line between these values.